# Excel VBA range property non contiguous ranges

Tags: vba, excel, range, autofill

I just want to fill different non contiguous ranges from an original cell containing `Sum(E1:E4)`. Here's the code (which doesn't work, just to get the idea clearer):

```
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K1:K4", "O1:O5", "Q1:Q5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to define the ranges somehow, either programatically or hardcoding, you could turn it into a subroutine, kind of like this:

```
Sub FillRange(Range rng)
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(rng), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Then you can call it:

```
FillRange("K1:K4")
FillRange("O1:O4")
FillRange("Q1:Q4")
```

One issue with this is you can't tell for sure that the destination ranges will be the same size as the range you have selected. You will probably want to code things around that. Without knowing more specifics, I cannot guess how you would want to do it, though.